# How normal shear stress vanish at the stagnant surface

Tags: fluid-dynamics

While I had always thought that it is so obvious that $\tau_ii$ (shear normal to x, y, or z planes) for a Newtonian, incompressible fluid is zero, now I find it pretty struggling to show it mathematically.
Imagining a fluid occupying upper half of 3D space. Let's assume Cartesian coordinates for simplicity. Incompressibility says that $\sum(dV_i/di)=0$ , $i=x,y,z$. applying no penetration and no-slip also gives $V_i=0$ at $z=0$.

I tried to somehow relate the incompressibility to the shear stresses so I looked at it by multiplying by $2\mu$ so I have $\sum\tau_ii=0$

now we know that the sum of normal shears are zero. I can think of a fully developed flow so I can assume each of $dV_i/di=0$ so that each of $\tau_ii=0$, but I believe there is a way to show it for a far more general case.

Comment: What is "parallel shear stress"? Do you mean normal stress? What is $\tau_ii$?

Comment: @Deep oops, edited! Yes, I meant normal stresses on the main diagonal of the stress tensor. I meant tau_ii, like tau_xx, tau_yy, tau_zz.

Comment: It is very confusing what you are asking.  Are you saying that at a free surface the shear stress is zero, or are you saying that, for an incompressible fluid, the viscous normal stress must be zero at a solid surface.

Comment: @ChesterMiller The second one, I knew it like, intuitively that it is zero, I was searching for mathematical proof to show it.

Comment: Oh.  OK.  Well, if the solid surface is the x-y plane, for example, we have from the no-slip BC, $\partial u/\partial x=0$ and $\partial v/\partial y=0$.  Therefore, from the continuity equation $\partial w/\partial z = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a stationary surface the flow is locally a simple shear flow. Let $\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x})$ be the velocity at position $\mathbf{x}$. If $\mathbf{x}_0$ is the position of a point on the surface then expanding the velocity about that point we get:
$$\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x}_0+\delta\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x}_0)+\delta\mathbf{x}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{u}|_{\mathbf{x}_0}+O(\delta\mathbf{x}^2)\\
=\delta\mathbf{x}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{u}|_{\mathbf{x}_0}+O(\delta\mathbf{x}^2)$$
because the surface is stationary. Neglecting terms of higher order, and since $\mathbf{u}|_{\mathbf{x}_0}$ is a constant tensor, we se that $\delta\mathbf{x}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{u}|_{\mathbf{x}_0}$ is the velocity field of a simple shear flow.

You can convince yourself that normal stresses are zero in a [simple shear flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_shear).